# Creating instances of a website dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-webpages

My plan is to create a simple chat website. I'm using asp.net web pages with razor and signalR for the chat. I have the default page and chat room page done but I dont know how to "dynamically" create multiple instances of the chat room page so that /chatroom/1 is a different chatroom than /chatroom/2.
[2 instances of chat room page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yGEb.png)

I'm assuming that this could be done by making 10 chatroom pages and naming them from 1-10 but I believe thats bad practice. I've done routing already so that /room/[number] opens an instance of the chatroom page but I dont know how to make them separate from each other. If code is needed I can upload it to github.

EDIT:
[Github](https://github.com/ziombo/chatroom)

Routing:

```
@using System.Web.Routing;
@{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{chatroom}/{number}", "~/room.cshtml", 
        constraints: new { chatroom = "room", number = "[1-9]"});
}
```

---

room.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

    string s = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    var RoomNumber = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("/") +1);
}


<div id="chat">
    <textarea id="chatBox" rows="40" cols="50" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Your message"/>
    <input type="button" id="msgSend" value="Send" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //simulate msgSend button with enter press when textbox focused
    $('#message').bind('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is enter key
            $('#msgSend').click();
        }

    });
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
                // Html encode display message. 
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                //get current time
                var currentdate = new Date();
                var datetime =
                +currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#chatBox').append('\n'+datetime+" "+encodedMsg);
            };
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#msgSend').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd say definitely upload the code - just edit your question and add the relevant code, it'll make answering your question much easier.

Comment: The thing is, that I don't really know which part of code is relevant. I don't even know how this whole thing is called and because of that I can't use google to find answer.

Comment: In that case, put up the routing code and the existing chatroom code you're using - too much code is better than no code at all.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully that's what You've asked for.

Comment: I wrote a chat application for my kids, but I didn't use this method.  I used ASP.Net, SQL Server on the back end, and ASP.Net Ajax controls.  I didn't have multiple chat rooms, but I could have easily had as many as I wanted by just having them select a room number, then only showing the messages in the table that have the specific room number.   You might want to specify jQuery here as the main tag?

Comment: Okay so 2 questions. 1) How would You "create" multiple chatrooms by having only 1 chatroom page? 2) How would You make messages from chat room #2 appear only in chat room #2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever occurs such problem, what solved it for me was SignalR grouping.

[SignalR multiple chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175173/signalr-multiple-chat-rooms)